# Laravel with SQLite doesn't keep Auth data

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, sqlite

I have project in Laravel 6 with MySQL database and its working fine. My client wants to use SQLite instead of MySQL database.

So i converted my existing database **from database.sql** to **database.sqlite** using following online tool
Online database conversion done here : https://www.rebasedata.com/
https://www.rebasedata.com/convert-mysql-to-sqlite-online

After that i have configured **database.sqlite** into **.env** file and into **config/database.php** file.

**Issue :** I am not able to go beyond login page. Every time i try to login it redirects me back to login page.

**Debug** : I reviewed that if I remove Authentication function then i am able to access controller which comes after login.

If I do comment to this line **$this->middleware('auth');** following function It starts working.

```
public function __construct()
{
    // $this->middleware('auth');
}
```

**Conclusion** : I found that I am not getting any value for **$user  = Auth::user();**

So I think that session is not getting generated and stored correctly with **SQLite database**

**Notes :**

- I have exported existing database using phpmyadmin and removed all
  unnecessary comments from database.sql file.
- I converted database.sql file online using this tool
  https://www.rebasedata.com/convert-mysql-to-sqlite-online
- As per my investigation Auth is not getting generated and stored.
- I am using default laravel Auth, I generated that using laravel terminal command.
- This setup works fine if I configure project with MySql database.
- SQLite database configure Path is correct. I found error of not proper path while configuring it and i solved that.
- I have already tested using this commands. : php artisan cache:clear --- php artisan route:cache --- php artisan config:cache --- php artisan view:clear

Any help are appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is your session driver set to? Have you run `php artisan config:clear && php artisan cache:clear`? It also might be worth looking at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53958991/laravel-doesnt-keep-session-when-use-sqlite-database

Comment: Session no idea but it should be save on Disk only instead of database. I have not made any change to default laravel setup configuration. And Yes I have executed following commands --> php artisan cache:clear
--> php artisan route:cache
--> php artisan config:cache
--> php artisan view:clear

Comment: What is `SESSION_DRIVER` set to in your `.env` file?

Comment: Its SESSION_DRIVER=cookie